# How do I persuade a remote Postfix to allow relaying from my ISP-assigned IP address?

Tags: postfix

Scenario: I'm testing an SMTP server on my local network, and I now need to check that it can send emails out to the net. The problem is, of course, that I'm going out via my ISP, and my ISP-assigned fixed IP address is not on DNS (I could put it on DNS, of course, but I couldn't set the reverse lookup, so it wouldn't help).

To get around this, I have Postfix set up on a remote server, and I'm trying to relay my outgoing messages through this server, to a local recipient on that server. This looks like it should be straightforward, but I'm obviously missing something. This is a new Postfix 3.6.4 setup, and `main.cf` contains:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 93.184.216.34/32
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, ...
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, ...
```

`93.184.216.34` is my ISP-assigned address, and my local network is `dummy-domain.com`. When I try to send an email to the server I get a failure, and the server log file says:

```
Oct 16 13:24:42 titan postfix/smtpd[19103]: connect from my-isp[93.184.216.34]
Oct 16 13:24:42 titan postfix/smtpd[19103]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from my-isp[93.184.216.34]: 450 4.1.8 <me@sub.dummy-domain.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<me@dummy-domain.com> to=<a-local-recipient-address> proto=ESMTP helo=<dummy-domain.com>
Oct 16 13:24:42 titan postfix/smtpd[19103]: lost connection after RCPT from my-isp[93.184.216.34]
```

`postconf` confirms `mynetworks`, but it also says this:

```
compatibility_level = 0
smtpd_relay_restrictions = ${{$compatibility_level} <level {1} ? {} : {permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination}}
```

Which I understand, perhaps incorrectly, to say that the default `smtpd_relay_restrictions` does *not* include `permit_mynetworks`, contrary to the documentation. So I explicity set this in `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
```

Restarted, And `postconf` now reports exactly the line above. However, it still doesn't work, and the server logfile still shows the same message. Any ideas? And how do I get `postconf` to show me the current real settings, without having to worry about the compatibility level? Thanks.

**EDIT**

as per anx's answer, it turns out that `smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks` ("Permit the request when the client IP address matches any network or network address listed in $mynetworks") isn't sufficient. You also need

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
```

with `permit_mynetworks` before `reject_unknown_sender_domain`. This all works without any changes to `/etc/hosts`, or any need to add anything to DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sender address rejected: Domain not found

This one nothing to do with your mail servers sending IP or its missing reverse association. You are using a **sender address** with a domain that cannot be found. Look for a statement like `reject_unknown_sender_domain` in your smtpd_*_restrictions, and prepend something that lifts this restriction for your needs.
It is probably the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` that you need to edit to proceed beyond this message. Or just configure an address as sender that actually can be found in DNS (again, this is independent from whether the hostname of the server sending the messages can be found in DNS).

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit the question to show a specific fix.

Comment: Note that you can also add your own answer, or edit an existing answer - whether it your own or not. We generally prefer the have the Question contain.. well, the question or problem description, and the answer or solution in the answer section.